# How to force bash to start at index 0 with select output?

Tags: bash, array, menu, select

Well, even some less-experienced `bash` users would know meanwhile about the fact that `bash` **arrays** would always start with index 0.
However, `select` will always do its own thing, as the following example shows:

```
#!/bin/bash
choices=(NONE nyc la chicago little_rock miami)

select choice in ${choices[@]}; do
  [[ " ${choices[*]} " == *" $choice "* ]] && break
done
echo "Choice was: $choice ; first element is ${choices[0]}"
```

Output is:

```
1) NONE
2) nyc
... etc. ...
```

**BUT** `${choices[0]}` will output 'NONE' nonetheless!
So I feel that somehow there must be a way to force `select` to start with **index 0**, not 1.

(Should anyone question the deeper sense of this: there actually is, especially when you have to skip processing frequently (ideally set as '0' in the menu) with more than 9 options and, for convenience's sake, you would put the least-used option as '10' so you may only have to type a single digit in almost every case.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to change the base of the menu's displayed item number. You mention in your question, "..even some less-experienced bash users would know (about) ... index 0".

Yes, that is correct, but the `select` menu was not devised for *bash users* (read "programmers")  - It was intended for *end-users* (pre GUI era)
 who would typically not know (or care) anything about bash.  Being comfortable with a zero based list is a programmer's thing (hence your preference), but it is definitely not something an end-user is used to, at all.